# How to get an integer from an object in PHP

Tags: php

I have an object that looks like this when I var_dump it:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#958 (5) { 
 ["id"]=> int(54) 
 ["user_id"]=> int(101)  
 ["score"]=> string(3) "3.0" 
 ["created_at"]=> string(24) "2015-09-14T17:49:42.649Z" 
 ["updated_at"]=> string(24) "2015-09-14T17:49:42.649Z" } 
}
```

I can get the string values just fine. For example:

```
$myObject->score;
```

Gives me what I want.

But if I try and get an integer (let's say user_id) the same way, I get a null value.

```
$myObject->user_id;
```

Any ideas here? I've played around with typecasting, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: [Can't reproduce your problem](https://3v4l.org/AkU2r) Give us an [MCVE] (FYI: You have an object in an array, so if you are not in a loop, use: `$xy[0]->user_id`)

Comment: It is an array containing an object... `$myObject[0]->user_id;`

Comment: You guys are totally right -- that fixed it. Any idea why I can get the strings, but not the integers with the method in my original example?

Comment: @Duplosion Are you sure you don't get any errors? Error reporting: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`